# Как сделать так, чтобы текст автоматически был записан в поисковую строку?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, функции, объекты

Есть объект с ключами, значения которых - текст, и этот текст должен появляться в placeholder поисковой странице на сайте. Первый ключ записывается по одной букве за раз, пока не будет создано все слово, а затем, по одной букве за раз, он полностью удаляется, а второй ключ записывается таким же образом в заполнитель. При нажатии на поиск, ключ начинает набираться заново.

Код был изменен. Помогали на английском стаке.
Сейчас проблема в том, что пишутся все ключи за раз, а должны по очереди, удаляя по букве предыдущий.

```js
let types = {
  phrase1: "Words",
  phrase2: "has been",
  phrase3: "deleted",
};

let curr = 0;

function writer() {
  let inp = document.getElementById("text");

  let text = Object.values(types)
  let sentence = text.join();
  inp.value += sentence.charAt(curr).replaceAll(" ", " ");
  curr++
  if (curr < sentence.length)
    window.setTimeout(writer, 250);

}
writer();
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <input id="text" type="text" placeholder=" ">
</div>
```

Comment: Не понял сути вопроса....

Comment: @Air не знаю как сделать, чтобы значение ключа было написано по одной букве, а когда ключ был написан, он удалялся по одной букве и начинал писать следующий ключ по такому же принципу.